# Webview in Nwjs can't rrun jquery

Tags: jquery, webview, nwjs

can someone give advise on what's happening when I load a webpage(local or remote) with jquery, error is always "$ is not defined". Note I have loaded jquery in my main html, where the webview element resides in, and I can use jquery in the context of main html. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Without source, it's difficult to say.  Are you just trying to load a different URL?  If so, window.location.replace("http://www.google.com"); will work fine.

Comment: Sorry, it is simple, just a element in main html " <webview id="mainpage" src="file:// /home/ur/Desktop/MyBrower/t1.html" partition="persist:trusted" style="display:flex; height:490px; width:100%;" allownw="allownw"></webview> " I have loaded jquery and use it in main html. When I try to change the src attribute of webview to a remote or local html which also jquery, the page doesn't work as expected. I tried to open the "embeded" html using web brower, it just worked fine.

Comment: I found the cause. Add nodeintegration attribute to the webview element. Really hard to find the answer since the webview is also used in android.

Comment: Ah yes, these things are a lot of fun - glad you got it!